# BackgroundWorker and CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker, collectionviewsource

How can i load my data in backgroundworker when using a CollectionViewSource? it throws an error because my CollectionViewSource is in UI thread.

This is all of my code (My background worker set in Xaml):

```
public partial class DepartmentsLookup : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;
    private ObservableCollection<Department> AllDepartmentsData;
    private ListCollectionView AllDepartmentsView;

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<Department> data = null;
        using (ArchiveEntities db = new ArchiveEntities())
        {
            data = db.Departments;
            this.AllDepartmentsData = new ObservableCollection<Department>(data);
        }
        CollectionViewSource departmentsSource = (CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("AllDepartmentsDataSource");
        departmentsSource.Source = this.AllDepartmentsData;
        this.AllDepartmentsView = (ListCollectionView)departmentsSource.View;
    }

    public DepartmentsLookup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker = ((BackgroundWorker)this.FindResource("backgroundWorker"));
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

thanx.

Comment: i dont see a backgroundworker. but nevertheless you have to use a dispatcher when you set the collectionview

Comment: What exception and where is it thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to work with WPF's Dispatcher object (Dispatcher.Invoke) to execute code on UI elements (when done from withni the BackgroundWorker). Maybe [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) can give you some more information.

Or [working with the WPF Dispatcher](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher).